# Imagemagick get real width and heigth

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, exif

```
magick identify -format "{w: %w, h: %h, o: %[orientation]}" img.png
```

I run this command to determine the dimensions of an image. The problem is, sometimes the orientation is such that w and h are swapped in practice. How can I get the "actual" dimensions, which a human sees when they open a picture? Is there a built-in command to get those, or a rule regarding when a particular orientation means I have to swap w and h?

Comment: You can try `-auto-orient` https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient

Comment: It may not work with `identify` so you may need to re-cast as `convert` with something like `magick INPUT.JPG -auto-orient -format ... info:`

Comment: That's correct! Auto-orient is not an option for identify. I unfortunately do not have write permissions on the system I am running on, only read. Is there a way to convert and use the output for identify without saving the file?

Comment: The command I suggested ends in `info:` so it should just display on the Terminal anyway.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [-auto-orient](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient) option:

```
magick INPUT.JPG -auto-orient -format "{w: %w, h: %h, o: %[orientation]}" info:
```